# JSONArray being lost on encode

Tags: java, arrays, json

Okay, this may be confusing.

I'm attempting to add a jsonarray to a jsonobject when a certain thing happens. Currently, the JSON file looks a bit like this

```
{
  "sweg":true,
  "bans":[
    {
      "1":[
         {
          "reason":"Hacking"
         }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "kicks":[
    {
      "1":[
         {
          "reason":"testing"
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, sorry if the formatting for the file is bad. I had to manually space it.

Next run, it should look something a bit like

```
{
  "sweg":true,
  "bans":[
    {
      "1":[
         {
          "reason":"Hacking"
         }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "kicks":[
    {
     "1":[
        {
         "reason":"testing"
        }
     ],
     "2":[
        {
         "reason":"meow"
        } 
     ]  
   }
 ]
}
```

When I say should, I mean what is intended. What is being added is the JSONArray "2" under "kicks".

But what turns out is this:

```
{
  "sweg":true,
  "bans":[
     {
      "1":[
         {
          "reason":"Hacking"
         }
      ] 
     }
  ],
 "kicks":[
   {
     "2":[
        {
         "reason":"meow"
        }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

What is ultimately being lost in the end is the "1" array under "kicks"

EDIT: forgot code, here it is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("testing.json"));
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("data", data);
    JSONArray jsonArray11 = new JSONArray();
    jsonObject.put("kicks", jsonArray11);
    JSONObject placeHolder2 = new JSONObject();
    jsonArray11.add(placeHolder2);
    JSONArray kick2 = new JSONArray();
    placeHolder2.p(2, kick2);
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
    kick2.add(jsonObject1);
    jsonObject1.put("reason", "meow");
    try {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("testing.json"), false));
        bufferedWriter.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: From the examples i can tell that instead of appending to json array you are adding the whole thing as new json object. just post some code so that i can help more.

Comment: Foolish me, will add now.

Comment: is "kicks" already there in "data", or you are newly creating it in this snippet.

Comment: oh oops I removed "data" from the JSON file a while ago. It was mainly an example to see if it worked, but it was there in all runs but thaty must be due to the fact that it was still in the code and being added.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough information, but it sounds like you just want to **append** data into `kicks`. You can do that like this:

```
$json = '{
  "sweg":true,
  "bans":[
    {
      "1":[
         {
          "reason":"Hacking"
         }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "kicks":[
    {
     "1":[
        {
         "reason":"testing"
        }
     ]
   }
 ]
}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($json);

$meow = '[
        {
         "reason":"meow"
        } 
     ]';  
$meowObj = json_decode($meow);

/* This will count the fields in kicks[0], increment, and create a few field 
   and name the new field the resulting number, then insert the new object. */
$jsonObj->kicks[0]->{count((array)$jsonObj->kicks[0])+1} = $meowObj;

print_r($jsonObj);
```

This will result in:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [sweg] => 1
    [bans] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [reason] => Hacking
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [kicks] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [reason] => testing
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [reason] => meow
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Not java but I'll possibly attempt to understand it.